# Vent to outside in gas hot water heater closet, can I seal it?

Tags: hot-water

In my laundry room I have a closet with a gas hot water heater and on the wall to the outside in this closet are two vents going outside.  This obviously presents a heat leak as you can feel the cold air coming into the laundry room.  I would like to close this up but I am not sure if that would present an issue due to the hot water heater being gas.  Is there a reason those vents are there and is there anything I can do about it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your gas water heater needs air to burn the gas. Without the vent, there's a possibility of air being sucked in through the flue instead, which could fill your house with carbon monoxide. So yes, you need the vent.

The exterior vent should have a flap/door on it that closes when there is no need for additional combustion air. If yours doesn't, then get it replaced with one that does.

Comment: Don't forget, it's an intake. So the flapper has to open **in**, not out.

Comment: Ah thanks, it doesn't have the flapper so I need that.